# Is a private member secure in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, private

I'm following [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/) JavaScript oop course. The course describes how you should declare a private variable inside objects for cases like passwords and bank accounts which cannot be changed from outside. the only access to private variables is through public method that has access to the private variable. then it gives this demo code to illustrate the point.

```
function Bird() {
  let hatchedEgg = 10; // private variable

  /* publicly available method that a bird object can use */
  this.getHatchedEggCount = function() { 
    return hatchedEgg;
  };
}
let ducky = new Bird();
ducky.getHatchedEggCount(); // returns 10
```

What i don't understand is how can the hatchedEgg variable be called as secured. 
As a user/hacker all i have to do is to guess the variable name that is being returned from the function getHatchedEggCount() . in this case hatchedEgg (which is not too difficult for a hacker) and then i can use this line to modify the private variable;

```
Bird.hatchedEgg = 20;
console.log(Bird) // returns { [Function: Bird] hatchedEgg : 20 }
```

Am i missing something ?

```
//-------------- Clarification Edit
```

Apparently the problem was with the freecodecamp console (A Bug) , it was changing the value of a private variable .
if you want you can try pasting the above code in this link and you will see. [freecodeConsoleLink](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/object-oriented-programming/use-closure-to-protect-properties-within-an-object-from-being-modified-externally)

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself? You don't have to be a hacker, you know the name of the variable already. Just try to console log ducky.hatchedEgg and see what you get. Spoiler: you won't get the value of the _private_ variable.

Comment: Nope. Zero “security”. Anything executing in JavaScript on a client is potentially insecure; mitigation is minimizing the potential (eg. XSS), properly ensuring operation security on the server (eg. HTTPs and anti-CSFR), and defining ‘trusted’ data / access. Minimally, if arbitrary JS can be injected, the entire object can likely be redefined.

Comment: BTW, what's JavaScript _oops course_?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ haha i meant oop see this link https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/object-oriented-programming/use-closure-to-protect-properties-within-an-object-from-being-modified-externally

Comment: Also the example you showed that a hacker might do, it won't change the variable hatchedEgg defined _inside_ the function Bird, it will just create a field in the Bird _object_. After all, functions are first class objects in JavaScript.

Comment: i can see that when i try the code in codepen, the problem was with freecodecamp console it was showing that hatchedEgg was getting changed

Comment: That's impossible. And, you should mention this in the question that in freecodecamp console it was getting changed. That way the [so] community can decide whether to close this question as "not reproducible"

Comment: I just tried out myself, and then in the link you provided in the "clarification edit", the _private_ variable is NOT changed - it still logs 15, not 20.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ i think you are trying to log using console.log(ducky.getHatchedEggCount()); // this will give you correct
try logging using console.log(Bird.hatchedEgg); // this gives 20

Comment: @silverkid  `hatchedEgg` and `Bird.hatchedEgg` are two different variables, please read my answer for an explanation.

Comment: That's exactly the point. Go through the answer I added. The reason you get 20 with `Bird.hatchedEgg` is because you just created it. To prove the line `Bird.hatchedEgg = 20` changes the value of the variable inside the function, you need to console log `ducky.getHatchedEggCount()` - if this gives you 20 I will stop talking :P

Comment: thanks guys jmaelaine and shadowfax reading now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting a little confused about the variables that are being created, and how each one is accessed.

You begin with a function:

```
function Bird() {
  let hatchedEgg = 10;

  this.getHatchedEggCount = function () {
    return hatchedEgg;
  };
}
```

This function does not have any properties.

When this function is called, it is simply attaching a `getHatchedEggCount` property to the `this` object. That `getHatchedEggCount` property is itself, a function, that references the `hatchedEgg` variable created when the `Bird` function runs.

Therefore we can do this:

```
// We call the 'Bird' function.
// As we are using the 'new' keyword, we create an empty context for the function.
// The empty context is referenced using the 'this' keyword inside the 'Bird' function.
// We assign 'getHatchedEggCount' as a method on the 'this' empty object
// We then return the 'this' object
// The 'ducky' variable now points to the returned 'this' object
// Therefore the 'ducky' variable is an object with a 'getHatchedEggCount' method
let ducky = new Bird();
```

and console logging gives the following output:

```
console.log(ducky);
// Output: Bird { getHatchedEggCount: [Function] }

console.log(ducky.hatchedEgg);
// Output: undefined

console.log(ducky.getHatchedEggCount());
// Output: 10
```

This is all to be expected, because `ducky` is an object with only a single property - the `getHatchedEggCount` method.

Most importantly though, notice what happens when we log the following:

```
console.log(Bird);
// Output: [Function: Bird]

console.log(Bird.hatchedEgg);
// Output: undefined

console.log(Bird.getHatchedEggCount);
// Output: undefined
```

We see that the `Bird` function is actually an empty object. It has no properties (that we have assigned ourselves), therefore `Bird.hatchedEgg` doesn't exist!

> So why can we access the `hatchedEgg` variable when calling `ducky.getHatchedEggCount()`? This is due to how closures work, but that is off topic. Needless to say, the `hatchedEgg` variable is ONLY accessible to the `getHatchedEggCount` function.

Now, if we say:

```
    Bird.hatchedEgg = 20;
```

We are adding a brand new property to the `Bird` function. So we can console log:

```
console.log(Bird);
// Output: [Function: Bird] { hatchedEgg: 20 }

console.log(Bird.hatchedEgg);
// Output: 20
```

We have added a new `hatchedEgg` property to the `Bird` function that didn't exist before!

Notice however, this is NOT the same property as the `hatchedEgg` variable that is used by the `getHatchedEggCount` function.

The original `hatchedEgg` variable is created inside the `Bird` function and is accessible inside the function body, but is not a *property OF* the `Bird` function object, therefore not accessible by doing `Bird.hatchedEgg`. Do you see the difference?

For example, run this code:

```
function Bird() {
  let hatchedEgg = 10;

  this.getHatchedEggCount = function () {
    return hatchedEgg;
  };
}

Bird.hatchedEgg = 20;
console.log(Bird.hatchedEgg);
// Output: 20

let ducky = new Bird();
console.log(ducky.getHatchedEggCount());
// Output: 10
```

Do you see why the `hatchedEgg` variable with the value of `10` is still inaccessible? It is not the same variable as `Ducky.hatchedEgg`.

Answer (score 1):

Calling  `ducky.hatchedEgg` (I guess you mean this instead of `Bird.hatchedEgg`)  directly won't give you any result (`undefined` to be precise). That's the whole point of the example i.e the private variables are not accessible directly from outside. They are accessed by a method which in turn could be/could not be exposed to outside. Security comes from that.

**Update** I re-read the question again and what you're doing is this: You're attaching a property `hatchedEgg` to `Bird` and setting a value to it.

`Bird.hatchedEgg = 20`

However, this `hatchedEgg` is NOT the same as `let hatchedEgg = 10;` that's originally defined within the function.

`ducky.getHatchedEggCount();` will still give you 10. `Bird.hatchedEgg` will give you `20` as you're attaching a property `hatchedEgg` to object `Bird` which is NOT the same as `hatchedEgg` declared inside the function `Bird`.

Also, `function`s first-class object and you can add/remove properties to it just like you'd do with any other object. However, in the last post, I intentionally tried to make distinction between `function` Bird and `object` Bird, to make the things clear. It's just like saying, `array`s are `objects` too. But you maintain a distiction in the conversations so as to simply the things. Anyway, updating this as I think that led to some sort of confusion.

Comment: i did not mean ducky.hatchedEgg i mean Bird.hatchedEgg.
Bird.hatchedEgg does logs undefined but see the edit i have made , i can still give new value to hathedEgg

Comment: correction: `Bird.hatchedEgg` will be `undefined` too. `Bird().hatchedEgg` will throw you an error.

Comment: Rahul, you say "bird is a function, not an object", but `Bird.hatchedEgg` is an object as well as a function. Functions ARE objects. So if you assign properties to it `Bird.hatchedEgg  = 5`, you can access those properties just like you would with a normal object `Bird.hatchedEgg`.

Comment: `Functions` are first-class objects - true. I intentionally didn't want go into that as I wanted to keep the distinction between `function` and `object`. Just like `array`s are object too, but for simple conversation we maintain the disctinction. But anyway when you're attaching a property, you're not doing anything with `let hatchedEgg` variable that is originally defined in the function. Anyway, see the updated answer now

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the freecodecamp topic, it is called closure. Just think of it this way using very trivial programming concepts:

> Variables declared inside a function are scoped to that function, there is no way to access those from outside the function. This is not only true for JavaScript, for all other languages.

Now as to why we can get the value of that scoped variable from outside is the *magic* of the closure. Since the question does not mention the word "closure" let alone ask about it, I will not go into the details of closure here.

And as for the code you said that a hacker could use to hack it, the line

```
Bird.hatchedEgg = 20;
```

only creates a property inside the **object** `Bird`. Another basic concept here - the function `Bird` is also a first class object in JavaScript, meaning it can have properties as well as functions just like any other objects. `Bird.hatchedEgg` refers to the property of the `Bird` object, whereas the variable declared inside the `Bird` function (with `let hatchedEgg = 10;`) is a local variable of the function, and the two are distinct. If that line were to change the value of the local variable declared inside the function, you should get the same result when you console log `ducky.getHatchedEggCount()`, but you wouldn't.